# Infopath form does not update after successfully publishing

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have followed the instructions at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262921(v=office.14).aspx to upgrade an infopath form in SP2010.  Everything looks like it works but the form does not update when I view it in the forms library.  I can even download the form to my PC from Central Management and it is the updated form.  I have deactivated and republished but that didn't help.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After Uploading form and activating it, run this command in sharepoint command shell:
**stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs**